# How can I verify this SMT specification containing an array selection as argument to a recursive function in Z3?

Tags: arrays, z3, smt, formal-verification

I'm researching automatic program verification using Z3 as SMT solver. More specifically, I'm trying to parse annotated programs containing a specification of their intended behavior, such that proof obligations can automatically be generated and verified using Z3. I'm aware that Dafny does exactly this, and does it really well. However, it is not at all clear how Dafny does this exactly internally and I'm trying to determine to what extend Z3 can be used for this purpose directly. Overall, this is working really well and Z3 is able to verify a lot of the generated proof obligations in a matter of seconds. However, as soon as I start to use a value that is selected from an array constant as an argument to a recursive function, an unexpected problem starts to occur.

The problem can be reduced to the following minimal example in SMT:

```
(declare-fun i () Int)
(declare-fun j () Int)
(declare-fun d () (Array Int Int))
(declare-fun Ld () Int)
(define-funs-rec ( 
  (sometimesFalse ((x Int)) Bool))
  ((ite (<= x 0) 
    false
    (ite (= x 1)
      true
      (sometimesFalse (- x 2))
    )
  ))
)

(assert 
  (let (
    (pre0 (not (= i j)))
    (pre1 (and (<= 0 i) (< i Ld)))
    (pre2 (and (<= 0 j) (< j Ld)))
    (pre3 (forall ((k Int))
      (=> 
        (and (<= 0 k) (< k Ld))
        (sometimesFalse (select d k))
      )
    ))
    (post (sometimesFalse (select (store d j 0) i)))
  ) 
  (and pre0 pre1 pre2 pre3 (not post))
))
(check-sat)
```

The above specification cannot be verified by SMT, it keeps running seemingly indefinitely. Now, if we change the `post` slightly by selecting from array `d` directly instead, we find that Z3 is able to verify the specification instantly (returning UNSAT). The SMT specification that can be verified is as follows:

```
(declare-fun i () Int)
(declare-fun j () Int)
(declare-fun d () (Array Int Int))
(declare-fun Ld () Int)
(define-funs-rec ( 
  (sometimesFalse ((x Int)) Bool))
  ((ite (<= x 0) 
    false
    (ite (= x 1)
      true
      (sometimesFalse (- x 2))
    )
  ))
)

(assert 
  (let (
    (pre0 (not (= i j)))
    (pre1 (and (<= 0 i) (< i Ld)))
    (pre2 (and (<= 0 j) (< j Ld)))
    (pre3 (forall ((k Int))
      (=> 
        (and (<= 0 k) (< k Ld))
        (sometimesFalse (select d k))
      )
    ))
    (post (sometimesFalse (select d i)))
  ) 
  (and pre0 pre1 pre2 pre3 (not post))
))
(check-sat)
```

Note that we explicitly state that `i != j`, thus `(select d i)` and `(select (store d j 0) i)` must be equivalent in the Array theory used by SMT-LIB.

Does anyone have any idea how SMT specifications like this can be verified by Z3? Since the SMT specifications are generated automatically, I'm looking for a way that can be applied to all cases where this problem occurs.

For anyone interested, the following is the annotated program that generates the problematic proof obligation, written in Dafny syntax. Note that Dafny is able to verify this program without any problems, which internally also makes a translation to SMT which is then verified using Z3. Thus, there must be a smart way to work around this problem.

```
method test(i: int, j: int, d: array<int>) returns (unused: bool)
    modifies d;
    
    requires i != j;
    requires 0 <= i < d.Length;
    requires 0 <= j < d.Length;
    requires forall k | 0 <= k < d.Length :: sometimesFalse(d[k]);

    ensures sometimesFalse(d[i]);
{
    d[j] := 0;
}

/**
    Recursive function that returns true iff x % 2 == 1.
*/
function sometimesFalse(x: int): bool
{
    if x <= 0 then
        false
    else if x == 1 then
        true
    else
        sometimesFalse(x - 2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an active research topic to figure out how to verify properties of recursive programs using automated techniques. Keep in mind that any interesting property of a recursive function will require induction to prove it. And SMT solvers do *not* do induction out of the box. Tools like Dafny and theorem provers like Isabelle/HOL/ACL2 etc., manage the induction themselves (with user help via annotations or tactics), and then formulate the induction proof and manage it themselves. They only use z3 as they "solve" each individual subgoal of that inductive proof. So, there's a level of "meta-reasoning" going on; and depending on the tool you get different levels of assurance. (In a theorem prover like Isabelle, you get very high assurance as it typically insists on "replaying" the proof. For Dafny, the level is also pretty high, but I'd say the trusted-code base is probably a bit larger.)

For a general introduction to the techniques involved, you can start by looking at Sacha Böhme's PhD thesis: https://d-nb.info/1023128497/34 It also contains numerous references for further reading. But in short, what you're trying to do is an area of active research and probably stack-overflow isn't the best venue to find answers in any more depth than this.